# How to apply style to a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I would like to hide the col12 class.but only col12 under the content-zone class because i have it in other places that i don't want top hide it. I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
.content-zone.col12 {
  display: none;
}
```

my code is :

```
<div class="content-zone">
<div class="col12">
</div>
</div>
```

If anyone can advise how I can selectively set a class attribute, I would appreciate it.

Comment: you are missing a space between the two classes `.content-zone .col12` Your currently saying this `<div class="content-zone col12">` for an immediate child use an `>` instead of a space.

Comment: See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292501/not-leaving-white-space-between-class-names

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space between the two class definitions.

```
.content-zone .col12
```

This will tell it to look for `content-zone` where `col12` is a child `n` levels deep.

However, what you're currently telling it, is to look for an element with both classes set on the same element aka:

```
<div class="content-zone col12">
```

As you can see here, when using a space it will match all `col12` within a `content-zone` no matter the depth:

```css
.content-zone .col12 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-zone">
  <div class="col12">Inside div 1</div>
  <div>
    <div class="col12">Inside div 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col12">Outside div</div>
```

For an immediate child use an `>` instead of a space. This will match the element only if it is a immediate child of `content-zone`. As you can [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) the second `col12` is ignore because it isn't a immediate child of `content-zone`:

```css
.content-zone > .col12 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-zone">
  <div class="col12">Inside div 1</div>
  <div>
    <div class="col12">Inside div 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col12">Outside div</div>
```